# Plotting a function with custom xticlabel in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to plot the function

[image]

I transform the above equation to

[image]

where x = z/R and

[image]

I want to plot the above function for positive values for z, which in turn implies positive value of x.

But the problem is, I want the xticlabel and yticlabel to be in units of R and [image] respectively.

So whenever the xticlabel is 1, it should show R, for 2, it should show 2R and so on and same for yticlabel.

I looked at the gnuplot documentation but there the example was given for plotting using a data file. So for custom xticlabels in gnuplot, I would generally do

```
plot 'datafile' using 3:4:xticlabels(1) with linespoints
```

where xticlabels(1) would mean to use the first column as the xticlabel,

Now I could write a function so that would input the first column and would return the number multiplied by R. But I am confused how to do this for a function as in my case.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to keep the relevant bits only? The model itself is not related to the actual problem. In addition, SO doesn't support LaTeX, and people usually use MWE or pass it as regular code.

Comment: @Bracula, I changed the latex and uploaded an image for the equation instead. But I have not changed the model. It explains why I need the graph to be how I want it to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for something like this:

- define `E(z)`
- set the x-range from 0 to the multiple you want, e.g. `[0:5]`
- use the argument `x*R` for the function `E(z)`
- `set format x "%gR"`

**Script:**

```
### tic labels as multiple of something
reset session

Q  = 1.602e-19      # elementary charge in C
e0 = 8.8542e-12     # epsilon0 in As/(Vm)
R  = 1e-6           # R in m

c    = Q/(4*pi*e0*R**2)
E(z) = 2*(1 - z/sqrt(z**2 + R**2))

set xlabel "multiple of R"
set xrange[0:5]
set format x "%gR"
set ylabel "multiple of Q/(4ε_0πR^2)"
set format y "%g"
set grid x,y

plot '+' u (x):(E(x*R)) w l lc "red" ti "E(z)"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks this was what I was looking for. Also what is "%g"? Can you tell me the topic name that covers this in the documentation. Also can you explain the line " plot '+' u (x):(E(x*R)) " or mention the topic that covers this in documentation.

Comment: @SumitGupta in gnuplot console check `help format_specifiers`. For `'+'` check `help special-filenames`  instead of `(x)` you could also use `1`, `(column(1))` or `($1)`.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you want to have `xtics` in some arbitrary units. In this case I refer to [gnuplotting.org](http://www.gnuplotting.org/multiplot-placing-graphs-next-to-each-other/), the code you need looks roughly like this:

```
set xtics ('-2R' -2, '-R' -1, '0' 0, 'R' 1, '2R' 2)
```

Comment: I did find this in the documentation. I wanted some function to do this automatically. But for now, I guess I have to go with this. Thanks.

Comment: @SumitGupta You could probably write a script that writes gnuplot scripts for you, I had to do something similar before. Anyway, if that resolves your issue, could you please mark it as solved?